SQLAlchemy: TypeError: MetaData.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bind'
Some background: I'm fairly new to SQLAlchemy, so I was going through the docs, trying to look for a way to perform queries on a pre-existing MariaDB database in Flask-SQLAlchemy. This led me to this: SQLAlchemy in Flask doc that seemed to answer my exact question. I made a small project based off of the "Declarative" section of the doc, then modified it for the "SQL Abstraction Layer" section, resulting in the following files and file structure:

sql_abstract

.venv

app

_init_.py
database.py
models.py
routes.py


config.py

run.py




_init_.py
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('config')

    from app.routes import register_routes
    register_routes(app)

    return app

database.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table
from config import conf

engine=create_engine(conf)
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)

models.py
from sqlalchemy import Table
from app.database import metadata

basic = Table('tblBasic', metadata, autoload=True)

routes.py
from app.models import basic

def register_routes(app):
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        res= basic.select(basic.c.name == "John").execute().first()
        return res

run.py
#get the app from the app folder's init.py
from app import create_app

flask_app=create_app()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    flask_app.run()

This results in the following error:
File "c:\...\app\database.py", line 5, in <module>
    metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: MetaData.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bind'

I am confused, both because this is verbatim code from the doc, but it's also mentioned in the SQLAlchemy docs that Metadata "Holds a collection of Table objects as well as an optional binding to an Engine or Connection."
I've tried specifically importing from sqlalchemy.schema, thinking that I may have imported a different class of the same name, but that didn't work.
I also tried using Metadata.reflect(bind=engine) like in this example, resulting in line 5 of database.py becoming:
metadata = MetaData().reflect(bind=engine)

and line 4 of models.py becoming:
basic=metadata.tables["tblBasic"]

but that resulted in metadata being a NoneType object instead.
Does anyone know what's causing this error and how to fix it? I'm at a loss.

Well, sqlalchemy.MetaData.__init__ doesn't take any argument called bind. Maybe SQLAlchemy in Flask was referring to an older version of SQLAlchemy when they wrote that.

I figured out how to fix it. I needed to go:
engine=create_engine(conf) metadata = MetaData() metadata.bind=engine. Though, I still don't know why this works.
